# Remove parameter from url not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to remove a url parameter `status` from the url but in the following alert, the parameter is still there.

```
var addressurl = location.href.replace(separator + "status=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i", "");
        alert(addressurl);
            location.href= addressurl;
```

How do i solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing regex with strings.

It should be:

```
var addressurl = location.href.replace(separator, '').replace(/status=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript context in web pages are **to the page** you are working on.

When you reload, redirect or move to any other page, javascript changes done in previous page will not be there. This has to be handled from server side.

Comment: what should happen is a the page should go to the new url without the parameter `status` nothing should be handles server side.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh repeats the last request to the server, which is going to ignore your javascript changes.  Instead navigate to the new url with `window.location = addressurl;`

Comment: tried this, the same url is alerted.  the parameter `status` is still there.

Comment: If your alert is showing the status parameter, the issue is with your replace, not with the navigation.

Comment: what is wrong with my replace?  is the regex wrong?

Comment: I don't know, I'll look.  Your original question was about why it disappeared on refresh, which is a different problem.